# C# Empty array creation

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having trouble with part of an array, I need to create a three dimensional array in a console program that starts empty and will have user assigned values after asking for user input. It does not need to persist past the initialization of the program.

I've created a few arrays that have values already in place to call upon, but I've never had to create an array that took the user's values that could then be called.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453.aspx

Comment: Well thats the problem, I don't know how to write it blank. I know double [ , , ] statistics = {{{ {then normaly here I would put the numbers, and another number} {then another number, etc}      I just don't know how to leave it blank then have user input into the array

Comment: Can't you get the input from the user first and then create the arrays based on those values?

Comment: Yes that it was I'm trying to do basically, I know how to ask for a value console.writeline then return the value console.readline, but how would I turn it into an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of a specific size by specifying the size inside the brackets, then you can fill in the data later.  Here's a sample of a three dimensional array with user-specified size.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter length of arrays (three dimensions, comma separated)");
string line = Console.ReadLine();
string[] stringDimensions = line.Split(',');
int[] intDimensions = stringDimensions.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();

var array = new string[intDimensions[0],intDimensions[1],intDimensions[2]];

for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < array.GetLength(2); k++)
        {
            array[i, j, k] = String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", i, j, k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm downvoting because I think your answer includes unnecessary lambda expressions and linq expressions that will confuse this beginner

Comment: Upvoting for actual giving an example and showing how to access the count for different dimensions. Rather see _dim1 = Convert.ToInt32(stringDimensions[0]); dim2 = Convert.ToInt32(stringDimensions[1]);_ but doesn't spoil the solution you gave.

Comment: @SamuelNeff Yeah, I mean have we gotten to the point where people can't give a simple, easy answer to someone who is new? I understand Linq and lambda expressions are popular, and add nice expressiveness to the language, but I'd be seriously frustrated if I were trying to learn and someone threw more complicated concepts at me than necessary. He's having trouble creating an array, why throw in LINQ, extension methods, and lambda expressions?!

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but yeah that is a bit too complicated for what I'm trying to do. I'm basically creating a small program that will ask a user to input 10 stats for 3 players for 2 games. I was thinking 3d array, but it doesn't need to be that complicated. I just need to ask for the stats from each game and player, then be able to print it out as an avg for either one or all three players. I was just trying to figure out how to write into an array and have it hold the data until called.  It is also my fault, I complicated my question.

Answer (score 0):

All arrays start out empty, that is all items in the array is set to the default value of the class. If it's an array of strings, for example, all items start out as `null`.

If it's an array of `int`, then all items start out as zero, so you would rather want an array of `int?` so that all items start out as `null`.

If by empty, you mean zero items, then you shouldn't use arrays, you should use a `List<T>`. They start out with zero items, then you add items to populate it.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx):

```
ArrayList mainArrayList = new ArrayList();

//creating a three dimensional arraylist
mainArrayList.Add(new ArrayList());
mainArrayList.Add(new ArrayList());
mainArrayList.Add(new ArrayList());

(mainArrayList[0] as ArrayList).Capacity = userSpecifiedSizeX;
(mainArrayList[1] as ArrayList).Capacity = userSpecifiedSizeY;
(mainArrayList[2] as ArrayList).Capacity = userSpecifiedSizeZ;
```